# Pandas to_csv() add double quotes starting from second row without quotes header

Tags: python, pandas

I want the header to be excluded and each value enclosed in double quotes when exporting to a CSV file.

This is my current code.

```
def csv_sample(df, file_path):
    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=file_path,
        index=False, 
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        header=True,
    )
```

This is the output.

```
"Field","Type","TxDate","TxTime"
"D/SSS","C","07/31/23","11:15:54 AM"
```

The desired output I want should be like this

```
Field,Type,TxDate,TxTime
"D/SSS","C","07/31/23","11:15:54 AM"
```

Is there a way to achieve my desired output using only the built-in to_csv function in pandas?

Comment: make 2 separate `.to_csv` calls

Answer (score 1):

We can use `append` mode:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    print(*df.columns, sep=',', file=f)
    df.to_csv(
        path_or_buf=f,
        index=False, 
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        header=False,
        mode='a'
    )
```

To be sure the columns are written to the file before continuing, we can pass `flush=True` into `print` (not necessary in this example). Also, note `mode='a'` with `to_csv` to append data to file, and `header=False` on second step.

*p.s. I should note that in the example above, `mode='a'` is not required, but only because we are using the same file buffer in both steps. However, we will need this if we separate writing headers and data, like this:*

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    print(*df.columns, sep=',', file=file)
...
df.to_csv(
    path_or_buf=file_path,
    index=False, 
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    header=False,
    mode='a'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit unconventional, but worked for me:
Add these lines after the `to_csv` command

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
df.columns = [col.replace('\"','') for col in df.columns]
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=file_path,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,index=False)
```

First you have ot export your csv. In the Second step you read it again and clean the column names from the double quting. Now your `dataframe` is as you wish.

cheers